# Nutch 2.2.1 & HBase - Can I create a new property in nutch-site.xml

Tags: web, web-crawler, nutch

I wanna develop a topical web robot using Nutch 2.2.1. And I wanna create a new property with some topic keywords,like following:

```
<property>
    <name>html.metatitle.keys</name>
    <value>movie,actor,firm</value>
    <description>
    </description>
</property>
```

Comment: What is your purpose for doing so?

Comment: I want to use key words in this property to filter web pages simply and imitate the usages of other properties by stating configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different solutions available for your problem:

1. Implementing a customized `HtmlParseFilter` plugin to filter pages
   based on your desired keywords. For more information about Nutch
   extension points and writing customized plugin for Nutch take a look
   at these manuals:

   http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/AboutPlugins

   http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample
2. Using an indexer to filter documents based on desired keywords;
   However, this solution is available if you have indexer in your
   system design architecture. In this case Apache Solr could help you
   for filtering documents before indexing. Here you have to implement
   a customized `UpdateRequestProcessor`. For more information about
   Solr and its extension points take a look at these pages:

   https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FrontPage

   https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor