# Nutch 2.2.1 & HBase - Infer whether to save Webpage into HBase or not according to some key words

Tags: web, web-crawler, nutch

Did function *`output`* in *`FetcherReducer.java`* response for storing webpage in HBase in Fetcher phase using code as followed?

```
context.write(key, fit.page)
```

If yes, is parameter `content` the content of fetched webpage? Can I use it to abandon webpage by comparing with key words defined by myself?
Otherwise, can you propose an effective approach to inferring whether to save Webpage into HBase or not  according to some key words?

Comment: Do you mean filtering urls by some keywords? or you want to filtering web site contents by some keywords?

Comment: Filtering web site contents by some keywords which mentioned in my another question [Nutch 2.2.1 & HBase - Can I create a new property in nutch-site.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786729/nutch-2-2-1-hbase-can-i-create-a-new-property-in-nutch-site-xml).